# Criar instalador no Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, instalador

Criei um instalador para a minha solução no Visual Studio 2019 usando o Setup Wizard (componente do próprio VS), e configurei ele de forma que ficasse ao meu gosto, mudei a aplicação de debug para release e aparentemente está tudo certo.

Porém quando eu executo o instalador, ele me diz que devo instalar o .NET Framework, de fato é um requisito para a instalação, mas eu já estou com ele instalado e mesmo assim essa janela continua aparecendo e não prossegue com a
instalação.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se eu colocar "Não" ele interrompe a instalação, e mesmo desinstalando o .NET Framework e fazendo a instalação dele por ai, quando reaberto ele retorna nessa mesma tela. Acredito que há N formas de fazer isso mas gostaria de criar o instalador pelo próprio VS, pensei em retirar o .NET Framework como requisito da instalação, mas não é possível.

Comment: Mas se você apertar no sim, ele faz a instalação e conclui?

Comment: Ele fecha essa janela, abre o navegador e baixa a versão descrita, eu tenho q abrir ele de novo, e ele abre novamente nessa mesma tela. Ele não continua a instalação automático